# Post php array with Guzzle

Tags: php, arrays, json, postman, guzzle

I know how to send post requests with Guzzle.
Here is an example oh what I’m used to do  :

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
                'exceptions' => false,
                'debug' => false,
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'timeout' => 30,
                'json' => [
                    data_1 => $data_1,
                    data_2 => $data_2,
                    data_3 => $data_3,
                ]
            ]);
```

However, I am having a problem sending a php array.

My array php is :

```
Array
(
    [lorem_1] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => 1189
            [data_2] => 100
            [data_3] => 110
            [data_4] => 120
        )

    [lorem_2] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => 54
            [data_2] => 130
            [data_3] => 140
            [data_4] => 150
        )

)
```

This is what I need to send. It is working in postman :

```
[
    {
        "data_1": "1189",
        "data_2": "100",
        "data_3": "110",
        "data_4": "120"
    },
    {
        "data_1": "54",
        "data_2": "130",
        "data_3": "140",
        "data_4": "150"
    }
]
```

So, I just need to convert my php array to something acceptable by Guzzle.

I’ve tested of course :

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
                'exceptions' => false,
                'debug' => false,
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'timeout' => 30,
                'json' => $my_array
            ]);
```

But it doesn't work.

I’ve tested :

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
                'exceptions' => false,
                'debug' => false,
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'timeout' => 30,
                'json' => array_values($my_array),
            ]);
```

But it doesn't work

I’ve tested :

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
                'exceptions' => false,
                'debug' => false,
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'timeout' => 30,
                'json' => json_encode(array_values($my_array))
            ]);
```

But it doesn't work. The json is valid and works in Postman but not in Guzzle. I guess it is a simple syntax issue or array format but I don’t know.

Do you know what to do ?

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work, what is the error?

Comment: also don't think there is any exceptions request option I guess you want to use `http_errors=>false`

Comment: @bhucho Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The web service  returns 200, the connection is ok, but the data is not updated. I think the PHP array is not formatted the way it should.

Comment: there is no need to mention application/json as header if you are using json request option, I 2nd one change json request option to `'json' => array_values($my_array)` also remove header as application/json and exceptions key and try again

Comment: @bhucho What confuses me, I should not send a JSON object but just an array “Arrays as JSON” (like in this example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) I will try your suggestion now but I will only know tomorrow if is works cause I have not access to my client admin.

Comment: @bhucho  Sorry, in my question, I've made a mistake, I wrote `'json' => $my_array = array_values($my_array);`because I adapt my code but I've already tried `'json' => array_values($my_array)`and it wasn't working.

Comment: If you are sending it then test it using a dummy request or make a request to a dummy url, you are saying it returns 200 but no data saved so it can be issue of the request accepting side even.